# error in arcsde service

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am getting an error message when atempting to Create a connection in Arc Catalog. The message is : Failed to Connect to database
SDE not Running on Server
Then I Check the Service esri_sde it has not started, so when I try to start it I get the message : The ArcSde Service(esri_sde)service on Local Computer started and them stopped.
i found sde_esri_sde.log file . the error messages are :
IDBInitialize::Initialize Failed
DB_open_instance() PCC_connect error: 2
init_DB DB_instance_open_as_dba: -51
DBMS error code: 2
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0: Login timeout expired
 i dont know what's wrong ... ?!
please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you check you connection properties. You were able to run sde post install cleanly? DId you used command line or GUI installation?

Can you connect to SQL Server via other tools? VIsual Studio or SQL Management?

Comment: i can connect to sql server via sql management . i used command line to start service but it didnt work(sdemon -o start -i esri-sde -s majid-PC)

Comment: @GISlove That just indicates that SQL Server is running, not that SDE is working. You need to resolve the SDE issue (perhaps a username/password problem?) before you can use ArcCatalog to connect to SDE.

Answer (score 3):

I only ever used ArcSDE with Oracle but I guess its probably the same. When you say you can connect in sqlserver under which username? sde? Does the sde schema (login in sqlserver?) exists and all the tables created?. You are either using the wrong username/password or the sde schema has not been created. Does the sdemon command gives you a different error?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have had this prob before.
If you are using (can't remember the name) ent/network authentication and your password has expired recently you need to go into the sql ?browser service and update the password. I also can't remember which service it is but I see brwoser, agent and sql server services. update one and see if sde will start.

Answer (score 1):

It's a better practice to use direct connections to your database instead of SDE services. SDE services will consume CALS and if you don't less CALS than users you'll have a first come first served problem. ArcGIS 10.1 uses direct connect exclusively. Also, the answer about network logins is good advice to consider. Look up the way to use direct connect in ESRI help docs.

Comment: I agree with you . direct connection is better because it doesn't need to start services